# Render script application on android ICS

Tags: android, 3d, renderscript

I want to create a live wall paper which has floating bubbles using renderscript on android ICS.How to proceed.Please need some inputs on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Renderscript Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html). Also read the Android Developers Blog [Introducing Renderscript](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/02/introducing-renderscript.html) and [Renderscript Part 2](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/renderscript.html). mobile tuts+ has a tutorial on [Getting Started With RenderScript on Android](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/getting-started-with-renderscript-on-android/).